# Are wrapping modes for cube-map textures supported in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

Are wrapping modes for cube-map textures supported? 
I have set wrapping modes to `GL_REPEAT` and used tex-cords `[-2,2]` but i can't see the repeated texture. It gets applied  once only. 
It seems that it is not possible with cube-map textures, why?

Here are my tex-cordinates:

```
#define eps1 1.0


 GLfloat tex_coords[] = {
   /* +X side */
   1.0, -eps1, -eps1,
   1.0, -eps1,  eps1,
   1.0,  eps1,  eps1,
   1.0,  eps1, -eps1,

   /* -X side */
   -1.0,  eps1, -eps1,
   -1.0,  eps1,  eps1,
   -1.0, -eps1,  eps1,
   -1.0, -eps1, -eps1,

   /* +Y side */
   -eps1, 1.0, -eps1,
   -eps1, 1.0,  eps1,
    eps1, 1.0,  eps1,
    eps1, 1.0, -eps1,

   /* -Y side */
   -eps1, -1.0, -eps1,
   -eps1, -1.0,  eps1,
    eps1, -1.0,  eps1,
    eps1, -1.0, -eps1,

   /* +Z side */
    eps1, -eps1, 1.0,
   -eps1, -eps1, 1.0,
   -eps1,  eps1, 1.0,
    eps1,  eps1, 1.0,

   /* -Z side */
    eps1,  eps1, -1.0,
   -eps1,  eps1, -1.0,
   -eps1, -eps1, -1.0,
    eps1, -eps1, -1.0,
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shamelessly stolen from [`ARB_seamless_cube_map`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/seamless_cube_map.txt).

> When sampling from cube map textures, a three-dimensional texture coordinate is used to select one of the cube map faces and generate a two dimensional texture coordinate ( s t ), at which a texel is
>   sampled from the determined face of the cube map texture. Each face of the texture is treated as an independent two-dimensional texture, and the generated ( s t ) coordinate is subjected to the same
>   clamping and wrapping rules as for any other two dimensional texture fetch.

The extension itself might also be of use to you.

Comment: I tried changing eps1 to 2,3,4 to repeat the texture but no use. I tried changing x,y coordinates keeping z constant but it does not give expected output. i have 3*3 texture.

Answer (score 1):

the s and t coordinates are based on the two non-major directions, but divided by the absolute value of the major direction. Since the major direction is the direction with the largest absolute value, the result will always be on the range [0, 1]. You can think of it as a built-in normalization of the 3D texture coordinate before doing the look-up.
In short, it is not possible to wrap the faces of a cube map.